# bowerInstall task alternative for Java?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, gruntjs

I'm working on a SpringMVC project and currently I'm organising the project structure for the "client" module. I'm using the webjars and wro4j projects with are great, to organise my JavaScript dependencies and concatenate and minimise my CSS/JS code.

What I miss is something exists in the "JavaScript" world that allows to use some HTML code depending on your environment. I'm talking about something like bowerInstall task.
What I would like is to have in my JSP code:
 * the includes to my JS files one by one, when working in "development" profile
 * a single file, as concatenation and minification, when working in "production" profile.

Next lines are from a HTML file in a Yeoman based project:

```
...
<!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/highlightjs/styles/monokai.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
...
```

When the grunt task runner is executed, if I'm working in dev mode it does not much but if we are in "prod" mode all the previous CSS are substituted by a line like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.css" />
```

Is this possible in Java??

Comment: Should be able to apply the same tools to the HTML (or JSP/XML) files anyway, no? Just do it before the JAR-building phase (if such resources are embedded).

Answer (score 1):

Is this possible in Java?? No.

However, you may try a couple of options.

1. **Google Pagespeed** - Check filter-css-combine documentation. Quick and dirty option, if you have an old project running on production.
2. **Grunt task** - Search for grunt-concat-css. 
   If you are using Bower and Yeoman, you would most probably know Grunt. Just hook on the grunt task to maven ( Search allegro/grunt-maven-plugin) or Gradle (Search com.moowork.grunt) before your WAR task.

this is not a comprehensive answer. Just pointers in the right direction.

Comment: I am sorry I cant post more than 2 links as my rep is quite low. :(